# trying to execute a small script from a variable, what is the right syntax?

Tags: bash

this doesn't work

```
X="bash -c 'for I in \$(seq 1 3); do sleep 1; echo \$I; done'"
$X
```

I get this

> I: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' I: -c:
>
> line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

but X looks file.

```
echo $X
```

> bash -c 'for I in $(seq 1 3); do sleep 1; echo $I; done'

and if I copy-paste that line into the bash prompt it works as expected.

my goal is to be able to pass a short ad-hoc script into a bigger script which runs it at some point.

If there is a better way to pass and execute literal script text I'd like to learn it.

Comment: Putting code in variables is a rather bad idea. Don't do that. If you need to package code for execution elsewhere, write a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
X="bash -c 'for I in \$(seq 1 3); do sleep 1; echo \$I; done'"
eval $X
```

Comment: This particular example works because word-splitting on `$X` only removes single spaces that are replaced identically by `eval` when it joins all its arguments back into a single string. More complex commands may not work as intended.